# Change the color of ivy-current-match depending on the caller

Tags: faces, ivy

When using `ivy`, say I want the current match to be red when calling `counsel-M-x`, but blue when calling `counsel-find-file`.

Is there a simple way of changing `ivy-current-match` depending on the function calling it?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no built-in support for this, but Ivy provides various hooks that you can plug your own logic into. Here is one way to achieve what you want, using the `ivy-hooks-alist` user option:

```el
(defvar my-ivy-match-faces
  '((counsel-M-x (:background "red")))
  "Alist mapping Ivy callers to a list of face specs.
Used by `my-ivy-remap-match-face', which see.")

(defun my-ivy-remap-match-face ()
  "Locally remap `ivy-current-match' to caller-specific face specs.
Which face specs to apply for each caller is determined by
`my-ivy-match-faces'.  If the current caller is unknown, or if
there is no entry for it, no remapping is applied."
  (when-let* ((caller (ivy-state-caller ivy-last))
              (specs  (alist-get caller my-ivy-match-faces)))
    (apply #'face-remap-add-relative 'ivy-current-match specs)))

(with-eval-after-load 'ivy
  ;; Remap the current match face as the default Ivy hook.  Note that specifying
  ;; a different hook for a particular caller will override this setting.
  (setf (alist-get t ivy-hooks-alist) #'my-ivy-remap-match-face))
```

The idea here is to look up the current Ivy caller (e.g. `counsel-M-x`) right after Ivy has set up the minibuffer, and then locally remap[1] the `ivy-current-match` face to a list of face specs of your choosing. In the sample code above, I have remapped the background to be red for `counsel-M-x` (see the variable `my-ivy-match-faces`).

Note that the way I modify `ivy-hooks-alist`, namely by setting `my-ivy-remap-match-face` as the default fallback hook, is kind of brittle. This is because any subsequent addition to this alist may override `my-ivy-remap-match-face`. Vanilla Ivy does not modify `ivy-hooks-alist`, so this is not an issue at the moment, but it may become one in the future or if you use other packages which modify this user option.

A more robust solution would then be to submit a feature request or PR[2] to make `ivy-hooks-alist` more flexible, e.g. by supporting multiple hooks per caller, and always running the default fallback hooks.

If that is not an option, you can advise[3] specific entries in `ivy-hooks-alist` to do your bidding. I will be happy to provide a sample implementation of this if asked.

- [1]: [`(elisp) Face Remapping`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html)
- [2]: https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper/issues
- [3]: [`(elisp) Advising Functions`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html)

Comment: this is almost perfect.  Your solution changes the color of the current line.  The only issue is that when I start typing, the matched characters show up in the default color of `ivy-current-match`.  I tried to fix this by also remapping `ivy-prompt-match`, but this doesn't seem to control the color of the matched characters.

Comment: @scaramouche I cannot reproduce what you describe. Please update your question with a step-by-step reproduction recipe, describing what you expect and what you actually see, ideally with screenshots, at every step.